# Powershell like Azure login in C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I want to build Azure admin app and i need to log in to my Azure account. The problem is that i want to do it in interactive way like in Powershell `Login-AzAccount` command. I don't want to register AzureAD app like in many tutorials in the web.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve it?

I've done it using .net library for Powershell.

```
        using (PowerShellExec commander = new PowerShellExec())
        {
            response = commander.RunCommand("Login-AzAccount");
        }
```

But is there any way to do it without powershell?

Comment: Why do not you register your admin app as an application in Azure AD ?  That way, Azure AD itself will show this login popup.   You can add policies to check role (to check if current user is admin then only authentication is successful )

Comment: For some reason i need to use login and password without registered AD app.

Comment: If you are building an admin app and want to authenticate users against Azure AD, then registering it with Azure AD is a must from security standpoint.. I have answered a very similar question before here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189040/c-sharp-console-app-azuread-how-to-mimic-powershells-get-azureaduser/54189977#54189977

Comment: PowerShell itself also uses an `appId:"1b730954-1685-4b74-9bfd-dac224a7b894"`. So my guess is that there would be a multi-tenant application registered to represent PowerShell as well.. we just don't see it in the regular interfaces/api's. Broader point still being, everything that works with Azure AD to authenticate and query information should have a registered application.

Comment: So, is there any possibility to get information about that app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

PowerShell uses ADAL - Active Directory Authentication Library.

There are all sorts of samples on the [official ADAL Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries).

And please do not even try the app id for PowerShell. It will not work for you. You have to register your own application. Follow the [tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app).