# Authenticate with Office365 Outlook mail server without registering Azure AD App

Tags: python, outlook, oauth, office365, email-client

I'm trying to write a script to access my Outlook university email inbox and I'm struggling with Microsoft's unorganized documentation. Right now I'm using powershell interop to access mailboxes via the outlook mail client I have installed.

[As far as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057250/11367507), the only way now is to register an app with Azure AD and get the API key from there. I don't have permission to do so. Is there a way authenticate using my email and password, probably like how email clients do?